# Logic Express: Spacebar isn't playing audio except in the arrange window

Tags: logic-pro

The title says it all: When I press the spacebar to play or pause audio, unless I'm in the arrange window, the screen flashes and nothing else happens. My friend who has Logic Pro says this isn't the case for him; is this a difference between Pro and Express, or do I have something set incorrectly? (This is in all projects, so I'm assuming it's a global setting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poring over the Logic manual, I finally found the answer: There was some sort of problem with the Key Commands assignments. (I suspect this happened when when I was attempting to program a controller some time back.) I reset the assignments and it took care of the problem.

From the Logic Express 9 user manual:

> **To initialize all key command assignments**
>
> Choose Options > Initialize all Key Commands in the Key Commands window.

(The Key Commands window is accesible from the main menu bar: Logic Express > Preferences > Key Commands...)